# Publisher and Subscriber using same node!

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anybody provide me an example for using publisher and subscriber with the same node? I want to publish a topic from node 1 and then subscribe to that topic from node 2 and then publish the subscribed data from node 2 to another topic!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229894/publisher-and-subscriber-using-same-node!/) by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2016-03-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a pretty frequently asked question, with lots of answers. The first four results that I get on Google all have reasonable answers with examples and discussions of the pros and cons of the various approaches:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/9339/subscriber-and-publisher-node-at-once-in-cpp/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/45867/publisher-and-subscriber-in-single-node/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/62327/how-to-create-a-combining-subscriber-and-publisher-node-in-python/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/48727/publisher-and-subscriber-in-the-same-node/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The above links didn't help me hardly at all, and I kept tripping across this thread while searching on this topic. Sorry for the very late post, but the below link really helped me out, and I wish I hadn't had to dig so much for it:

- http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning

Hope it helps someone else out too!

---

Originally posted by [KenLafond](https://answers.ros.org/users/34140/kenlafond/) with karma: 61 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I kind of like this one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lR3cK9ZoAF8
Hope this may help

---

Originally posted by [lochlomond](https://answers.ros.org/users/44598/lochlomond/) with karma: 61 on 2019-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WangTCU](https://answers.ros.org/users/60422/wangtcu/) on 2020-10-03**:
Please trust this guy. His youtube link helped me!